# Proving identity in asymmetrically encrypted communication

Tags: public-key, key-exchange, identity-based-encryption

Let's assume such a scenario.

- Person **A** will broadcast his public key and
- person **B** will broadcast his public key. They can now communicate.
- But let's say that suddenly another person **C** will write to person **A** impersonation person **B**.
- How can a person **B** prove their identity.

We can implement a *signature* system. Person **A** will generate a certain signature and gives it to person **B**, to always join it to the message, targeted to person **A** and prove the identity in such way, but the same problem will still appear. How will a person **B** know that the signature received is from a person **A**. Is there a way to prove the identity in such a system.

Comment: "the same problem will still appear" --> the point of a digital signature is that person C can't generate valid signatures, only person A can. So why do you say that the same problem still appears?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the primitive you're looking for is [Authenticated Key Exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_Key_Exchange).

There are a lot of AKEs out there, only some of which require signatures. See chapter 5 of the [key exchange book](http://link.springer.com/10.1007/978-3-662-58146-9) for an overview. Some of the more popular ones are [X3DH](https://signal.org/docs/specifications/x3dh/), the more general [Noise framework](http://noiseprotocol.org/noise.html), and [HMQV](https://eprint.iacr.org/2005/176).

Answer (score 0):

When you assume that C acts as an adversary, is eavesdropping and capable of constructing messages based on the acquired information, you have to design your protocol with care. This stems from the fact that C could potentially  relay, replay, and construct messages. Therefore, you need to prevent replay and man-in-the-middle attacks, furthermore handling for multiple, (simultaneous) protocol sessions.
You already realized that a static signature might not be enough. Essentially, your problem is the motivation for authentication protocols and their design is not trivial: if you take a look at the Needham–Schroeder protocol [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needham%E2%80%93Schroeder_protocol) or the Woo-Lam protocol [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woo%E2%80%93Lam) you will see that unforeseen attack vectors could break your protocol as both examples are insecure in their original versions.

Basically, some best practices for secure protocol design are:

- Make maximally pessimistic assumption
- Put the sender and receiver in messages (i.e., their public keys)
- Use encryption to ensure that only the correct receiver can read the content
- Use nonces / timestamps to get freshness
- Generate nonces yourself to prevent replay attacks
- Always sign and encrypt components together

But still: there are protocols considered secure that do not follow all points and insecure protocols that do.
In any case, you would want to analyze your protocol (semi-)automatically using for example model checking or theorem proving.

Answer (score 0):

I came to the conclusion that I replied myself with my own question. If persion **A** will generate a signature for persion **B** and send it using persons **B** public key to encrypt it, only these two people will know the secret. So now it is crucial that the person **B** always joins his signature which has been received from a person **A**. In order to identify the recipient of the message, we use a public key and to identify the person from which we received messages we use a generated signature. In this way, we can map the public key with the generated signature one-to-one. Thanks to the comment of [mikero](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/users/192/mikero), I looked at my question from a different angle. Also, I will take into account the algorithms suggested by [p-rathje](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/users/100522/p-rathje) when creating a key-exchange system.